# Uint32Array( buffer, byteOffset, length ) does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/br230737) I can create a `Uint32Array` in 3 ways:

1. `new Uint32Array( length );`
2. `new Uint32Array( array );`
3. `new Uint32Array( buffer, byteOffset, length );`

First and second method work great, but third didn't work for me. What's wrong in this code?

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var uint32s = new Uint32Array(buffer, 4, 4);
uint32s[0] = 0x05050505;
var uint8s = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i =0; i< 8; i++)
{
    alert(uint8s[i]);
}
```

This works fine, but of course `byteOffset = 0`.

```
var uint32s = new Uint32Array(buffer);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the documentation is incorrect here in that `length` is not a number of bytes but the number of 32-bit integers that the `Uint32Array` will contain.

**Exhibit A**

Changing the code to `var uint32s = new Uint32Array(buffer, 4, 1);` works.

**Exhibit B**

The [documentation for Uint32Array on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint32Array) says that `length` is a count of items, not bytes.

**Exhibit C**

It doesn't really make sense to have the constructor accept a length in *bytes*. What should happen if `length` is not a multiple of 4?

Comment: @Demion: For completeness, you might want to read the full answer (I just finished it).